# How to set breakpoint for Xcode debugger Assert asCopy error

Tags: ios, xcode, breakpoints, assert

When testing my iPhone app, I get this in the log:

> 2019-08-31 23:31:11.161429-0500 MyAppName[22493:7512886] [Assert] Cannot be called with asCopy = NO on non-main thread.

There's a bunch of asynchronous things going on, so I don't know what line in my code is causing that message in Xcode's log window.

How can I set a breakpoint or otherwise determine what line of my code is responsible for that message?

(There are other cases where Xcode shows error messages with no connection to the line of responsible code.  Is there a general way to handle that?)

Comment: I saw a similar problem with same error that you got. Maybe you can check this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52808945/dispatchqueue-cannot-be-called-with-ascopy-no-on-non-main-thread